# A* Graph Search Good Heuristic

Tags: java, path-finding, heuristics

I'm implementing the A* path find algorithm for a simple multi exit maze with varying distances, however I am unable to find an appropriate heuristic, it seems to perform a breadth-first search.

Cost is initial set to 1

Heres my attempt:

```
public void search(Node startNode, Node goalNode){
    System.out.println("Search Started");
    boolean found = false;
    boolean noPath = false;

    Queue<Node> open = new PriorityQueue<Node>(10,new Comparator<Node>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Node t, Node t1) {
            return Double.compare(t.getCost(), t1.getCost());
        }
    });

    visited[startNode.getX()][startNode.getY()] = true;
    order[startNode.getX()][startNode.getY()] = 0;
    startNode.setCost(h(startNode, goalNode));
    open.add(startNode);

    while (found == false && noPath == false) {
        if (open.isEmpty()) {
            noPath = true;

        }else{

             Node current = open.remove();

            if(current.getX() == goalNode.getX() && current.getY() == goalNode.getY()){

                System.out.println("found Node");
                printOrder();
                found = true;
                break;


            }else{
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                    Node nextNode = getAction(current.getX(),current.getY());
                    System.out.println("getting node:" + nextNode.getX() + " " + nextNode.getY());
                    int g2 = current.getCost()+cost+h(current, goalNode);
                    System.err.println(g2);
                    nextNode.setCost(g2);

                    if (nextNode.getX() != -1) {
                      count++;
                      visited[nextNode.getX()][nextNode.getY()] = true;
                      order[nextNode.getX()][nextNode.getY()] = count;
                      open.add(nextNode);

                    }
                }    
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Heuristic function

```
public int h(Node current, Node goal){

    return (goal.getX() - current.getX()) + (goal.getY() - current.getY());

}
```

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: What does the maze look like? In typical mazes, Manhattan distance is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the typical maze - one exit, only one path, path-width=1 - the A* has no advantage over breadth-first. Its difference is only visible for maps like you would see in strategy games where there is an advantage to trying to walk in the by-air-direction of the target and where the distance previously traveled has significance. If you like, have a look at the other algorithms:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm

Comment: Addition: A* is a heuristic breadth-first so it will find the shortest of the paths first. Your disappointment that it does not perform better than the strict breadth-first comes from the fact that there is no advantage to the goal-estimate labeled `h(x)` on the wikipedia page on A*. In fact, you have to have `h(x)=0` (so just leave it out of the heuristic)! If you dont do this then A* will prefer the by-air-direction of the goal and produce sub-optimal paths.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got it now I've applied a different weight to each node and it finds the shortest path. I'll look at the Wiki page linked to for alternative algorithm.

Comment: It will not produce suboptimal paths, assuming admisible heuristic (eg. eucleidian distance). But it most likely will find it in worse time, becose of open set management.